# How to send an object of custom class from Android to Java Server?

Tags: android, database, json, servlets, entityobject

I have created several classes in  android client application corresponding to each database table (just like concept of Entity-Objects).

i want to retrieve data from database of the server to android client application and then assign that returned data set to objects of those created classes to further process the data and apply some logic.

I also want send data from android to server in the form of objects to process them on server or insert/update in the database.

(I can send the data to  Servlet using HttpClient and HttpPost but don't know how to send objects and how to receive result set of database in the form of objects).

I'm new to client-server programming so my this approach might be wrong, if so then please correct me. 
any sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

normally you would send some kind of String to the server which represents your Object. You could do that by generating JSON. There are nice libraries like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) which can help you with that

Comment: +1 but I would prefer to use Native library and classes, instead of depending on Third-party API/library.

Comment: That would be of course be a nice approach. Android already allows you to use org.json.JSONObject for such uses.

Comment: Thanks Tim!
I've Tried alot but I could not do it successfully as i already mentioned i'm new to this.
Can you please show me the in couple of lines to do that thing.

Comment: Imagine you have an Object called "Person" with a String name and an int age. What you're going to do is creating a new JSONObject jsonPerson and afterwards use jsonPerson.put("name",name) and jsonPerson.put("age",age). When sending to the server make sure to use jsonPerson.toString().

Comment: @TimMesserschmidt exactly!! Agree with Tim

Comment: what if the result set returned by database is too long, and we want to send each row as an object of class "Person" to the android client so that all "methods" and "attributes" can be accessed on android client in same way as on server  (or vice versa)